# "Still" and "Yet" as Conjunctions

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, word-usage

I know there are already many posts on **still** and **yet**, but I really find it difficult to use them as conjunction as in following sentences:

> 1. *It's a small car, **yet/still** it's surprisingly spacious*
> 2. *He has a good job, and **yet/still** he never seems to have any money*
> 3. *The weather was cold and wet. **yet/still**, we had a great time.*

So my question is when should I use **yet** and when should I use **still**, when using it as a conjunction, and what is the correct option for sentences above?

Comment: I believe some people have a stylistic preference for *and yet* over *yet* at the beginning of a clause, but I can't find a reference. Somehow *and yet* sounds better (especially at the beginning of a sentence).

Comment: 1b (with 'still') requires a semicolon. 3a (with 'Yet') does not have the comma.

Comment: See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129115/what-is-the-difference-between-better-yet-and-better-still

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Yet* is a [conjunction meaning *nevertheless* or *however*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yet#Conjunction). While *still* may appear in conjunctive phrases like *but still,* it is not itself a conjunction. Therefore:

> It's a small car, **yet** it's surprisingly spacious.
>
> The weather was cold and wet, **yet** we had a great time.

You can use either word in conjunctive phrases. [*Yet* usually carries a sense of negation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yet#Adverb), so *and yet* means the same thing as *but still.*

> He has a good job, **and yet** he never seems to have any money.
>
> He has a good job, **but still** he never seems to have any money.

Comment: As an adverb, _yet_ is an NPI, so it's not surprising that it invokes a negative feel. As a conjunction, it's a version of _but_ that falutes slightly higher, and can indicate a slightly different version of surprise. Compare _sadder but wiser_ with _sadder yet wiser_.

Comment: 'Still' is also used as a conjunctive adverb cf 'however'. It's a small car, yet it's surprisingly spacious. // It's a small car; however, it's surprisingly spacious. It's a small car; still, it's surprisingly spacious

Answer (score 0):

I agree. **Yet** means however and still. We can put 'and' before it. Sentences include:

> I bought ice cream on a freezing winter's day, yet it still melted.

**Yet** shows contrast between two statements.

Comment: Hello, chile. ELU expects supporting references, linked and attributed, to back up claims (even when correct).  Also, OP gives three double examples. // If 'yet means however', does this mean that 'The weather was cold and wet. However, we had a great time.' may be written 'The weather was cold and wet. Yet, we had a great time.'?